# ImportError: html5lib not found, please install it

Tags: python, pip, conda

I am trying to run a Python script; however, when executing it, I get the error:

```
ImportError: html5lib not found, please install it
```

What I tried to do is 'pip install html5lib' and 'conda install html5lib.' After that, I reopened Visual Studio Code, but the error remains.

How is it possible to solve this

Comment: you may have several versions of python. check which version you are running the script with. for this version, check whether the medul is installed with `python pip list`.

Comment: Ok, I have Python 3.10.6. How do I run 'pip list' for this specific version? The command 'python pip list' outputs a list with 'html5lib' in it.

Comment: are you sure you only have this version? you can check in your script and the terminal which version/path you are using `import sys
print(sys.path)`. You can use a specific version by specifying the absolute path to the executable when calling your script

Comment: Command 'print(sys.path)' outputs only 3.10.6.

Comment: What does `pip show html5lib` output?